# Problema com alinhamento de string

Tags: java, android, string

Estou com um problema no meu projeto Android que não estou conseguindo resolver. Eu tenho uma série de strings que são somadas formando uma string maior conforme o seguinte exemplo:

```
String teste1 = "O.P.                Processo            Célula";
String teste2 = "20350               A                   005";
```

Porém ao ser exibido em tela a letra A e o 005 não ficam debaixo das palavras "Processo" e "Célula". Eu até colei esse código no Skype para passar para uma pessoa e não veio alinhado também. Porque isso ocorre?

Comment: @AlexandreMarcondes, eu resolvi reformular minha pergunta para expressar melhor meu problema

Comment: @anovaesneto Transferi a resposta pra outra, só vi que era duplicada quando começaram a votar pra fechar. ( http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/2468/como-alinhar-strings-para-utilizar-em-um-listview )

Comment: OK @Bacco tentei excluir essa pergunta mas não consegui, então marquei como duplicada e votei para fecharem também

Comment: Não acho que isso seja uma duplicata. A outra pergunta pergunta como alinhar colunas numa `ListView`, enquanto essa questiona porque alinhar caracteres por colunas não resulta em um texto alinhado. A outra pede pela forma correta de fazer uma coisa, essa indaga porque a forma errada está errada.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral o próprio autor comentou que ele resolveu reformular para expressar melhor o problema. Creio que essa pergunta deva ser fechada mesmo não sendo tecnicamente uma duplicata é a intenção que vale e o autor fez as duas para resolver o mesmo problema. Isso que eu levei em consideração para marcar. A outra expressa melhor o problema dele e resolve.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcondes Eu não concordo que seja a intenção que valha. A utilidade do Stack Overflow é que essa pergunta vai ser útil para outras pessoas, e mesmo que o autor esteja tentando resolver um único problema, outras pessoas podem querer saber porque alinhamento por caracteres não funciona sem que isso esteja relacionado com `ListView`.

Comment: Bom, se a pergunta tiver com respostas mais claras com código eu até concordo @DanielC.Sobral, mas como ela está parece muito mais superficial que a outra e as duas acabam respondendo a mesma coisa, apesar de estarem diferentes. Dá uma editada então para termos algo melhor então. Sinceramente da forma que está eu não acho que valha a pena manter.

Answer (score 9):

Para isto você precisa usar fontes monoespaçadas, como por exemplo Courier.

Fontes monoespaçadas, diferentemente das fontes proporcionais, são aquelas em que todas as letras tem as mesmas larguras. Veja só a comparação:

**Exemplo 1**

XMILSW
WWMWMW
i01 .m

**Exemplo 2**

```
XMILSW
WWMWMW
i01 .m
```

Perceba que no primeiro caso as letras não se alinham e no segundo sim.

Dê uma olhadinha na documentação do [typeface MONOSPACE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#MONOSPACE) para ver algumas opções nesse sentido.

> Considere o [Grid View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) como alternativa. O Grid View permite ter várias colunas separadas, alinhadas independentemente do conteúdo.

Comment: Desculpe a pergunta, mas você saberia aonde eu mudo a fonte então em um projeto android? Estou usando um listView

Comment: Acrescentei uma referência à API na resposta, espero que ajude.